# Pagination in web scraping using jsoup in java swing

Tags: java, swing, pagination, jsoup

```
private void EducationWorld_Webscrap_jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                                                
     try
     {
         Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.educationworld.in/institution/mumbai/schools").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
         Elements  links=doc.select("div.instnm.litblue_bg");
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder ();
         links.stream().forEach(e->sb1.append(e.text()).append(System.getProperty("line.separator")));
         jTextArea1.setText(sb1.toString());
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
}
```

This is showing data. But there is pagination. How to fetch data of next five pages?

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately I've achieved what you're after, as you can see in the code block below. I've added comments that hopefully describe each step if you were not sure what is happening.

I tried playing around with the pagination settings of the site but they seem to only allow increments of 5 results per request so there wasn't much leeway, and you need to pass the starting point before it can retrieve the next 5 results.

Therefore, I've had to include it in a `fori` that loops `32` times. Which equates to `158` schools, divided by `5` equals `31.6` or rounded `32` Of course, if you only want the first `5` pages you can change the loop to loop only `5` times.

Anyway on to the juicy bit;

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Loop
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        final StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try
        {
            // Parameter pagination counts
            int startCount = 0;
            int limitCount = 5;

            // Loop 32 times, 158 schools / 5 (pagination amount)
            for( int i = 0; i < 32; i++ )
            {
                // Open a connection to the supplied URL
                final URLConnection urlConnection = new URL( "http://www.educationworld.in/institution/mumbai/schools" ).openConnection();
                // Tell the URL we are sending output
                urlConnection.setDoOutput( true );
                // The stream we will be writing to the URL
                outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

                // Setup parameters for pagination
                final String params = "qstart=" + startCount + "&limit=" + limitCount;
                // Get the bytes of the pagination parameters
                final byte[] outputInBytes = params.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
                // Write the bytes to the URL
                outputStream.write( outputInBytes );

                // Get and read the URL response
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( urlConnection.getInputStream() ) );
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String inputLine;

                // Loop over the response and read each line appending it to the StringBuilder
                while( (inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
                {
                    response.append( inputLine );
                }

                // Do the same as before just with a String instead
                final Document doc = Jsoup.parse( response.toString() );
                Elements links = doc.select( "div.instnm.litblue_bg" );
                links.forEach( e -> sb1.append( e.text() ).append( System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) ) );

                // Increment the pagination parameters
                startCount += 5;
                limitCount += 5;
            }

            System.out.println( sb1.toString() );
            jTextArea1.setText(sb1.toString());
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                // Close the bufferedReader
                if( bufferedReader != null )
                {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }

                // Close the outputStream
                if( outputStream != null )
                {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
            catch( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps and you get the outcome you want, if you require anything describing just ask!

Comment: This display all data in console output. But when I write jTextArea1.setText(sb1.toString());   in place of  System.out.println( sb1.toString() );   It display only 3 schools name.

Comment: Amended the `StringBuilder` and the `setText( sb1.toString() )` See updated answer this should now be putting all the schools in your text area.

Comment: @D.Rudra Did the update work for you? If you could let me know that would be great!

Comment: Thanks Tom C Sir. Now all school name is showing. It is taking 2 minutes to load data but It is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the request needs to be executed 32 times. Therefore, 32 requests would be slow, maybe there could be a way to improve the execution speed but at least it works. So if you are happy with the answer could you please accept it? Thanks!

Comment: can I show the message box like "Please wait..data is loading" in JOptionPaneShowMessage ? If yes then how ?

Comment: Yes you could show a message box or some form of progress bar while the results are retrieved, though this is probably another question.